# Why does Google Colab RAM (free version) crash when SMOTE is run for oversampling?

Tags: python, machine-learning, smote

I am working on a machine learning project, related to the diagnosis of Alzheimer's Disease. The data needs to be oversampled due to the classes being imbalanced. Thus, SMOTE is used.

The code block, containing SMOTE, is given below. Google Colab RAM crashes when this code block is encountered.

```py
sm = SMOTE(random_state=42)

train_data, train_labels = sm.fit_resample(train_data.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE * IMG_SIZE * 3), train_labels)

train_data = train_data.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)

print(train_data.shape, train_labels.shape)
```

The code, before this snippet, is given here.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import os
from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree, remove_tree

from PIL import Image
from random import randint

from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import matthews_corrcoef as MCC
from sklearn.metrics import balanced_accuracy_score as BAS
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix

import tensorflow_addons as tfa
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential, Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras.applications import InceptionV3
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator as IDG
from tensorflow.keras.layers import SeparableConv2D, BatchNormalization, MaxPool2D

base_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Alzheimers_Diag_GCUThesis_2021/Alzheimer_sDataset/'
root_dir = "./"

test_dir = base_dir + "test/"
train_dir = base_dir + "train/"
work_dir = root_dir + "dataset2/"

if os.path.exists(work_dir):
  remove_tree(work_dir)

os.mkdir(work_dir)
copy_tree(train_dir, work_dir)
copy_tree(test_dir, work_dir)
print("Working Directory Contents:", os.listdir(work_dir))

WORK_DIR = './dataset'

CLASSES = [ 'NonDemented',
            'VeryMildDemented',
            'MildDemented',
            'ModerateDemented']

IMG_SIZE = 176
IMAGE_SIZE = [176, 176]
DIM = (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)

ZOOM = [.99, 1.01]
BRIGHT_RANGE = [0.8, 1.2]
HORZ_FLIP = True
FILL_MODE = "constant"
DATA_FORMAT = "channels_last"

work_dr = IDG(rescale = 1./255, brightness_range=BRIGHT_RANGE, zoom_range=ZOOM, data_format=DATA_FORMAT, fill_mode=FILL_MODE, horizontal_flip=HORZ_FLIP)

train_data_gen = work_dr.flow_from_directory(directory=WORK_DIR, target_size=DIM, batch_size=6500, shuffle=False)

#Retrieving the data from the ImageDataGenerator iterator

train_data, train_labels = train_data_gen.next()

#Getting to know the dimensions of our dataset

print(train_data.shape, train_labels.shape)
```

Comment: Please see how to post a [mre] (emphasis on *ninimal*); **remove** code that is irrelevant to the issue (including irrelevant imports). See why [a wall of code isn't helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/).

Answer (score 0):

Images processing tasks are often memory heavy and from what I've seen SMOTE also eats up the RAM quite fast. You're trying to make new samples but there's simply not enough memory in Colab to store them.

You could try to lower `IMG_SIZE` although it doesn't guarantee anything.